# Script to remove user profiles using powershell

Tags: powershell, user-profile

I'm trying to build a powershell script that I can use to delete all or some of the user profiles on multiple pc's since they often cause the drives to go full.

I found the current script which I got to work for me, but I'd like to optimize it so I can input or import a list of computers where I want him to remove all the user profiles from.

Can you guys help me to input this feature?

Current Code:

```
$ExcludedUsers ="admin","test"
$RunOnServers = $false
[int]$MaximumProfileAge = 0 # Profiles older than this will be deleted

$osInfo = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem

if ($RunOnServers -eq $true -or $osInfo.ProductType -eq 1) {
    New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "Stone Profile Cleanup" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    $obj = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_UserProfile | Where {(!$_.Special -and $_.Loaded -eq $false )}
    #$output = @()

    foreach ($littleobj in $obj) {
        if (!($ExcludedUsers -like $littleobj.LocalPath.Replace("C:\Users\",""))) {
            $lastwritetime = (Get-ChildItem -Path "$($littleobj.localpath)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\UsrClass.dat" -Force ).LastWriteTime
            if ($lastwritetime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$MaximumProfileAge)) {
                $littleobj | Remove-WmiObject
              #  $output += [PSCustomObject]@{
              #      'RemovedSID' = $littleobj.SID
              #      'LastUseTime' = $litteobj.LastUseTime
              #      'LastWriteTime' = $lastwritetime
              #      'LocalPath' = $littleobj.LocalPath
              #  }
            }
        }
    }

#$output | Sort LocalPath | ft
#$output | Sort LocalPath | ft * -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 4096 | Out-File -filepath "C:\MyOutput.TXT" -append -Encoding Unicode
    Write-EventLog –LogName Application –Source "Stone Profile Cleanup" –EntryType Information –EventID 1701 -Category 2 -Message ("Profiles older than $MaximumProfileAge days have been cleaned up")
}$ExcludedUsers ="adminbholemans","testbholemans1"
$RunOnServers = $false
[int]$MaximumProfileAge = 0 # Profiles older than this will be deleted

$osInfo = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem

if ($RunOnServers -eq $true -or $osInfo.ProductType -eq 1) {
    New-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "Stone Profile Cleanup" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    $obj = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_UserProfile | Where {(!$_.Special -and $_.Loaded -eq $false )}
    #$output = @()

    foreach ($littleobj in $obj) {
        if (!($ExcludedUsers -like $littleobj.LocalPath.Replace("C:\Users\",""))) {
            $lastwritetime = (Get-ChildItem -Path "$($littleobj.localpath)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\UsrClass.dat" -Force ).LastWriteTime
            if ($lastwritetime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$MaximumProfileAge)) {
                $littleobj | Remove-WmiObject
              #  $output += [PSCustomObject]@{
              #      'RemovedSID' = $littleobj.SID
              #      'LastUseTime' = $litteobj.LastUseTime
              #      'LastWriteTime' = $lastwritetime
              #      'LocalPath' = $littleobj.LocalPath
              #  }
            }
        }
    }

#$output | Sort LocalPath | ft
#$output | Sort LocalPath | ft * -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 4096 | Out-File -filepath "C:\MyOutput.TXT" -append -Encoding Unicode
    Write-EventLog –LogName Application –Source "Stone Profile Cleanup" –EntryType Information –EventID 1701 -Category 2 -Message ("Profiles older than $MaximumProfileAge days have been cleaned up")
}
```

I found this piece of code for the computer input but I'm not sure how I can implement it properly.

```
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName SRV1,SRV2,SRV3 -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.LocalPath.split('\')[-1] -eq 'UserA' } | Remove-CimInstance
```

Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: something like [this script](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/4908-delete-remote-user-profile)?

Answer (score 0):

Get-CimInstance -ComputerName SRV1,SRV2,SRV3 -Class Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { $_.LocalPath.split('')[-1] -eq 'UserA' } | Remove-CimInstance

Do u test it before? Work OK?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).